# Is the data() function intended to provide functionality other than holding reactive properties?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I saw a Vue component where the programmer (not well versed in Vue, he did not realize what he was doing was uncommon) used the `data()` function to carry more tasks than just return the `data` structure:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "testing",
        data() {
            console.log("hello world")
            return {
                myvar: null
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is `data()` supposed to have extra functionalities beyond handling the reactive properties?

Comment: There's probably no good justification for it, on the other hand it's not a problem in this example.  Anything you might think to do there should probably be done in a lifecycle hook like `created` instead, or in an imported API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do side effects in `data` but it wasn't intended for that. Its sole purpose is to define initial data for the instance to make it reactive.

`data` is executed between `beforeCreate` and `created` lifecycle hooks. If some logic should be evaluated before data becomes available, it belongs to `beforeCreate`.

Since `console.log("hello world")` side effect doesn't affect the component, it doesn't serve any purpose except notifying that `data` is called (this is already known but can be confirmed by setting a breakpoint).